# C: confirmation of simple arithmetic output

Tags: c, math, int, undefined, unsigned

Can I confirm that the following C code gives undefined result for b:

```
unsigned a = 0;
int b = a - 1;
```

Comment: I see always -1 as result: http://ideone.com/cjArR http://codepad.org/xoAD6LIJ

Comment: @hari: the reasoning is this: `a` is unsigned, while `-1` is int, so `-1` is promoted to unsigned. So we have `b = a + UINT_MAX`. But if `UINT_MAX > INT_MAX`, then this result does not fit into the representable range of `b`, which therefore gives undefined result

Comment: @tyty: Thanks. how did you come up with `b = a + UINT_MAX` ?

Comment: @hari: C converts int to unsigned in a well defined way: if int is non-negative, the unsigned result has the same value. If int is negative, the unsigned result equals the int value added to `UINT_MAX + 1`. But I find the expected result counterintuitive, so I doublecheck on this forum just to make sure.

Comment: @tyty: There is no `-1` in the code. The `-` operator is the binary one (subtraction), not the unary one (negation).

Comment: @R.. You are right regarding the operator. But `a - b` equals to `a + (-b)`. I find it easier to explain using the second form.

Comment: `a-b` and `a+(-b)` are not equivalent. The former is well-defined for signed ints when `b` is `INT_MIN` and `a` is negative. The latter is not.

Comment: @R.. You are right. For 2's complement system, if the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero is allowed, then that would be the value of `INT_MIN`. On such system, if int is 32 bit unpadded, the value is -2147483648. But `INT_MAX` would be 2147483647. So -INT_MIN is larger than `INT_MAX` and therefore cannot be represented by an `int`. So the result of `-b`, (where `-` is the unary operator) would be implementation defined in such a corner case.

Comment: Not implementation-defined. Undefined. Per 6.5 Expressions: "If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @R.. Thanks. I need further clarification on 6.5, 6.3.1.3 and 6.5.3.3 which I will ask in a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(§6.3.1.3/3): "...either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

On typical twos-complement hardware, I'd expect the result to be -1.

Note that the result is implementation defined, not undefined.

Comment: can I clarify what is the difference between implementation defined and undefined?

Comment: @tyty: Implementation-defined means that your particular implementation must pick some consistent rule, and document what that rule is.  If it were undefined, on the other hand, then it need not be consistent or documented.

Comment: @tyty: Implementation defined essentially means, As per the implementation by the Compilers,the standard leaves out some feature to the whims and fancy of Compilers.But you can rely that a specific compiler will give you the same result for scenarios which invoke the behavior.Undefined means anything can happen,in this case the standard does not mandate the compiler to do anything specific,the program might crash or not or dragons might fly.You cannot expect the same behavior for scenarios which invoke the same behavior even for the same compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit type conversion takes place when you assigned **unsigned** to **int**. So, its not undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It always giving the values

```
 a=0,b=-1
```

only if you want to check it out in the online [c compiler](http://codepad.org/3g1tQYDC)